# Google Analytics Mapping Exception

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8, google-analytics, mapping, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics and trying to integrate it with my windows phone app. I followed the steps like creating a tracking ID, installing the nuget package and editing the information in analytics.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<analytics xmlns="http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/ns/easytracker">
  <trackingId>UA-49305542-1</trackingId>
  <appName>MyPhoneApp</appName>
  <appVersion>1.0.0.0</appVersion>
</analytics>
```

I even added a tracker in my app initializer

```
    GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("MainPage");
```

When I try to execute the code in emulator, I am getting an exception. Details below

**Message :**

An attempt to override an existing mapping was detected for type GoogleAnalytics.Core.IPlatformInfoProvider with name "", currently mapped to type GoogleAnalytics.Core.PlatformInfoProvider, to type GoogleAnalytics.PlatformInfoProvider.

**Stack Trace :**

at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypeMappings(IUnityContainer container, Boolean overwriteExistingMappings, Type type, String name, IEnumerable1 fromTypes, Dictionary2 mappings) 
at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container, IEnumerable1 types, Func2 getFromTypes, Func2 getName, Func2 getLifetimeManager, Func`2 getInjectionMembers, Boolean overwriteExistingMappings) 
at MyPhoneApp.IocContainer.AppContainer.RegisterMySdk() 
at MyPhoneApp.IocContainer.AppContainer.Initialize(Frame rootFrame, DataContext dataContext) 
at MyPhoneApp.App.d_*5.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b*_0(Object state)

can someone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Unity Container provides an option to override the default behavior.

```
  App.Container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromApplication(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            overwriteExistingMappings:true);
```

Adding the extra parameter solved the problem.